# Error in Sitecore Content Editor after update to 6.6

Tags: editor, sitecore

I have Sitecore instance 6.6 updated from 6.3. After the update an exception occurs when right-clicking on the left side of the content tree. That's the space where you can choose to show the lock icon and so on. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

This is the error message:

```
[ArgumentException: Empty strings are not allowed.
Parametername: header]
   Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ArgumentNotNullOrEmpty(String argument, String argumentName) +241
   Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.Menu.Add(String id, String header, String icon, String hotkey, String click, Boolean check, String radiogroup, MenuItemType type) +68
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorForm.Gutter_ContextMenu() +637

[TargetInvocationException: Ein Aufrufziel hat einen Ausnahmefehler verursacht.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct&amp; sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks) +808
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +38
   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.MethodCommandProcessor.Invoke(PipelineArgs args) +427
   Sitecore.Nexus.Pipelines.NexusPipelineApi.Resume(PipelineArgs args, Pipeline pipeline) +330
   Sitecore.Pipelines.Pipeline.DoStart(PipelineArgs args) +208
   Sitecore.Pipelines.Pipeline.Start(PipelineArgs args, Boolean atomic) +182
   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.MethodCommand.Execute(CommandContext context) +499
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +530
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorPage.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +25
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +108
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3394
```

Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of things you need to check and doublecheck.

1) Is your Sitecore.Kernel.dll in /bin the correct version for 6.6. A very common mistake to make is, to go through the upgrade fine and then rebuild your project - forgetting that your local obj and bin folders hold Sitecore DLLs for 6.3 that then gets copied to /bin.

To fix this, first try and take the entire /bin directory from your 6.6 zip and copy/replace it to your website /bin. See if the issues goes away.

2) If not, check our commands.config (located in App_Config/Include) and make sure it's the right version for 6.6.

These two, is where I would start looking first.

Comment: I just checked those. Both are fine. They come from the 6.6 update.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what caused this error. The items in the core database of that menu lost their language versions during the update. After creating the language versions of those items in the core db, the menu shows up again.